# return available rooms by time

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a table which containts reservs for rooms.

`+----+-------+------+
| id | time  | room |
+----+-------+------+
|  1 | 12:00 | A    |
|  2 | 13:30 | A    |
|  3 | 15:30 | A    |
|  4 | 20:00 | A    |
|  5 | 10:00 | B    |
|  6 | 21:00 | B    |
+----+-------+------+`

I want to get rooms which has capacity by time +- 1 hour (interval +-1 hour).
For example if i say 19:00, i have to check there is no reservavtion between 18:00 to 20:00.

**Some example:**
I enter 18:30 => SQL give me back A and B room *(check reservs between 17:30 and 19:30)*
I enter 16:00 => SQL give me back A room *(check reservs between 15:00 and 17:00)*
I enter 20:30 => SQL give me back no room *(check reservs between 19:30 and 21:30)*

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: And what type is `time`?

Comment: Surely a `date` should come into play somewhere

Comment: Sorry, postgresql. Time column is timestamp without time zone, i only skipped date part.

Comment: "I enter 20:30 => SQL give me back no room _(check reservs between 19:30 and 21:30)_": shouldn't that return _B_? 21:00 is **between** 19:30 and 21:30

Comment: No, if there is any reservation between 19:30 and 21:30 (+-1 hour to 20:30), that room is not good for us. Room is only good, if there is no reservation in that interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's relatively ease to find the reserved rooms, and you want all others so this will work:

```
select distinct room from res
except
select distinct room 
from res 
where time between cast('2015-01-01 16:00' as timestamp without time zone) - interval '1 hour' and cast('2015-01-01 16:00' as timestamp without time zone) + interval '1 hour'
order by 1;
```

> I enter 16:00 => SQL give me back A room (check reservs between 15:00
>   and 17:00)

Room A is reserved at 15:30 so I think the query should return B, and it actually does.

Answer (score 0):

So, an hour ago I knew nothing about postgresql but here's a proof of concept that I threw together. There's probably a much more efficient way of doing this:

```
create table foo
(
  id serial,
  time timestamp,
  room varchar(1)
);

insert into foo (time, room) values 
         ( '2015-01-21 10:00:00', 'B')
        ,( '2015-01-21 12:00:00', 'A')
        ,( '2015-01-21 13:30:00', 'A')
        ,( '2015-01-21 15:30:00', 'A')
        ,( '2015-01-21 20:00:00', 'A')
        ,( '2015-01-21 21:00:00', 'B'); 


select distinct room from foo where room not in
(
    select distinct room from foo
    where time between
    '2015-01-21 16:00:00'::timestamp - interval '1 hour' and
    '2015-01-21 16:00:00'::timestamp + interval '1 hour'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few parts to this.
First any reservation that falls within an hour of the desired time on either side makes the room ineligible.
We can solve that with the following:

```
time + interval '1 hour' > @param AND time - interval '1 hour' < @param
```

Second this needs to be applied to each room independently.
Which we solve using window functions.
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html

The end result will look like this:

```
SELECT distinct room, NOT bool_or(time + interval '1 hour' > @param AND time - interval '1 hour' < @param) OVER (PARTITION BY room) as available FROM reserv;
```

Notice we are applying an aggregate `NOT bool_or(...)` that is saying that if any of the current reservations produce a conflict we will return false.
Then the `Over (PARTITION BY room)` ensures that we only look for conflicts within the scope of a single room.

Example:

```
SELECT distinct room, NOT bool_or(time + interval '1 hour' > '2015-01-21 16:00' AND time - interval '1 hour' < '2015-01-21 16:00') OVER (PARTITION BY room) as available FROM reserv;
```

Will produce:

```
+====+=========+
|room|available|
+====+=========+
|  A |    F    |
|  B |    T    |
+====+=========+
```